# Importing a shapefile and keep getting error with PostGIS manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, database

I am new to PostGIS and using pgAdmin. I have tried to import a shapefile into PostGIS manager and it gives me this message:

```
Importing with configuration: ex_hzfi99mczhvqbnkrya6ryz35mveyt_osm_point, public, geom, C:\Users\rhiem\Desktop\Database file\Slovenia\ex_hzfi99McZHVQbNkryA6Ryz35mveYt_osm_point.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Point
PostGIS type: POINT[2]
Unable to convert data value to UTF-8 (iconv reports "Invalid argument"). Current encoding is "UTF-8". Try "LATIN1" (Western European), or one of the values described at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html.

Shapefile import failed.
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].